# Poynting vector for a plane wave in a medium with relative permittivity $\varepsilon_r$

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

The time-averaged Poynting vector can be written:
$$\tag{1}
\langle \boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{r})\rangle=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re}\left\{\boldsymbol{E}(\boldsymbol{r}) \times \boldsymbol{H}^{*}(\boldsymbol{r})\right\}
$$
My Professor has written in his notes that for a plane wave traveling along the $z$-direction in a medium with relative permittivity $\varepsilon_r$ we have:
$$\tag{2}
\langle \boldsymbol{S}\rangle=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\varepsilon_{r}} \varepsilon_{0} c\left|E_{0}\right|^{2} \hat{\boldsymbol{z}}
$$
but I fail to see how that follows from eq. (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a trivial example.
$$ {\bf E} = E_0 \sin(kz - \omega t)\ {\bf \hat{x}}\ ,$$
which is a plane-polarised wave travelling along the z-axis.

The H-field of this wave, in a medium with relative permittivity $\epsilon_r$, is in phase with the E-field and has a direction such that ${\bf E} \times {\bf H}$ is along the z-axis.
The H-field amplitude is given by the E-field amplitude divided by the impedance of the medium, which is $E_o \sqrt{\epsilon_r \epsilon_0/\mu_0}$.
$$ {\bf H} = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon_r \epsilon_0}{\mu_0}}E_0 \sin(kz - \omega t)\ {\bf \hat{y}}\ .$$

Then use ${\bf S} = {\bf E} \times {\bf H}$ to find
$$ {\bf S} = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon_r \epsilon_0}{\mu_0}}E_0^2 \sin^2(kz - \omega t)\ {\bf \hat{z}}\ .$$

Take the time-average of the $\sin^2()$ term, note that $\mu_0 = 1/\epsilon_0c^2$ and we get
$${\bf S} = \frac{\sqrt{\epsilon_r}\epsilon_0 cE_0^2}{2}\ {\bf \hat{z}}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

It follows because a plane wave will have the direction of propagation, $E$ and $H$ fields related by
$$ \textbf{E}=\frac{1}{Z}\hat{\textbf{k}}\times \textbf{H},$$
where $Z=\sqrt{\mu_{0}/\epsilon_{r}\epsilon{0}}=\frac{1}{c\epsilon_{r}\epsilon{0}}$ is the impedance of free space and $\hat{k}$ is the unit vector in the direction of propagation (orthogonal to both fields).

If you now substitute into your eq (1), for $\textbf{E}\times\textbf{H}^{*}=\textbf{E}\times(\frac{1}{Z}\hat{\textbf{k}}\times \textbf{H}^{*})$, and use the vector identity for cross product of triple vectors
$$ \textbf{A}\times(\textbf{B}\times\textbf{C})=\textbf{B}(\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{C})-\textbf{C}(\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{B}),$$

and the fact that $\textbf{E}\cdot\textbf{E}^{*}=|E|^{2}$, you get your answer in your eq (2).